# How should I implement a copy constructor & assignment operator for a matrix class?

Tags: c++

I have a matrix class with fields like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T **matrix = nullptr;
    int rows; 
    int cols;
```

At this stage, I have written an assignment operator and a copy constructor. But firstly, there is code duplication, how can it be avoided, and secondly, they seem very similar to me, how can these methods be improved to look normal?

```
Matrix(const Matrix &matrix_) : rows(matrix_.rows), cols(matrix_.cols)
        {
            matrix = static_cast<T **>(new T *[rows]);

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                matrix[i] = static_cast<T *>(new T[cols]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix_[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &matrix_)
        {
            if (&matrix == this)
            {
                return *this;
            }
            clean();

            rows = matrix_.rows;
            cols = matrix_.cols;

            matrix = static_cast<T **>(new T *[rows]);

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                matrix[i] = static_cast<T *>(new T[cols]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix_[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        void clean()
        {
            if (cols > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    delete[] matrix[i];
                }
            }
            if (rows > 0)
            {
                delete[] matrix;
            }
        }
```

According to the condition of the assignment, it is forbidden to use STL containers, I must implement the controls myself

Added move semantics

```
Matrix(Matrix &&other) noexcept : rows(std::move(other.rows)), cols(std::move(other.cols)), data(new T(rows * cols))
{
    other.data = nullptr;
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
}

Matrix &operator=(Matrix &&other) noexcept
{

    if (&other == this)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    if (rows != other.rows && cols != other.cols)
    {
        std::cout << "Error assigning matrices of different sizes" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    clean();

    std::swap(data, other.data);
    std::swap(rows, other.rows);
    std::swap(cols, other.cols);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off with a 1D array that you use `T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) { return matrix[row * cols + col]; }` to access. Copying one of those is probably as quick as it can be. Use a `vector<T>` for `matrix` and you get most of it for free.

Comment: Do you really need changing cols and rows in runtime? If not, consider declaring them in the template parameters and use `std::array`, you will not need custom the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

Comment: Do you have a reason for wanting to use manual memory management in your Matrix class?  Is it some kind of assignment (no pun intended) or something?  If not, @ted's suggestion has a lot of merit.

Comment: As does @273K's for that matter, but for different reasons.

Comment: Yes, this is a task. The teacher forbade the use of containers from the STL, I have to implement resource management myself

Comment: Ok, then use _one_ pointer. You can even make a small smart pointer class to deal with the memory management

Comment: Why one and not double? And what about the assignment operator and the assignment constructor. They should be very similar (including code duplication)

Comment: Your copy constructor can call your assigment operator (as `operator=`) if you want, and if the pre-conditions are right.  Initialising your member variables at the point they are declared helps with this.

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко Please check my answer. I guess this is what you want. I edited to use manual memory management instead of `std::vector` Of course the constructors and destructors will be needed...

Comment: _"Why one and not double?"_ - Because it's slower and much more error prone.

Comment: It doesn't look like those `static_cast`s are needed. Casts should make you suspicious that you may be doing something wrong.

Comment: Did the assignment specify the semantics of matrix assignment for matrices of different dimensions?

Comment: @einpoklum, do you mean not only square matrices? If so, then yes, matrices can be of different sizes

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко: I mean, what's supposed to happen if you assign a matrix of size 10x20 to a matrix of size 1x1? Is this supposed to fail, or is the target matrix now supposed to become a 10x20 matrix?

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко What should happen when you assign a 2x3 Matrix to a 3x2 Matrix?

Comment: I haven't gotten around to handling this error yet, but I think an error should be raised

Comment: Why would you use move semantics with primitives? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you require matrix assignments only between values with the same number of rows/columns, it will make doing things like putting them in a vector impractical unless every matrix put in the vector has the same size. You can make sizes invariant by putting the rows and cols in the template. Then everything will work since different sizes are different classes.

Comment: @doug It is not enough. It also requires to know the matrix size at compile time...

Comment: There is an explicit site for code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com **BUT** note the code has to work first. So if you can test your code with unit tests and it works as expected, you can get it reviewed there. Though you will probably want the whole class reviewed, not just part of it.

Comment: @simre My concern was that without being able to assign matrixes with different rows/cols, things like `std::swap(mat1, mat2);` wouldn't work. And this is used by vector.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use a 1D array then. It will be much cleaner and simpler and faster than an array of pointers to arrays... You can do something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    // Note: Assuming T is a trivial type, most likely a fundamental type...

    T* data; // Flattened matrix with size = rows*cols. Be careful,
             // for really big matrices this multiplication could overflow!!!

    // You can use unsigned type since negative size is a nonsense...
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;

public:
    Matrix(const Matrix& other) 
        : data(new T[other.rows*other.cols])
        , rows(other.rows)
        , cols(other.cols)
    {
        /// You can do this:
        /// for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; ++i)
        ///    data[i] = other.data[i];
        /// or simply call the copy assign operator:
        operator=(other);
    }

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other)
    {
        // This is only for matrix with the same dimensions.
        // Delete and allocate new array if the dimensions are different. 
        // This is up to the OP if he can have differently sized matrices or not...
        // Also assert will "disappear" if NDEBUG (ie. in release) is defined.
        assert(rows == other.rows);
        assert(cols == other.cols);
        for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; ++i)
            data[i] = other.data[i];
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note: You will also need to define the constructor(s) and destructor of course...
I'm pretty sure you can't make it much simpler than this...

Comment: Thanks! But I have a small question, since we only have a single pointer, then the clean function (for the destructor and possibly the future move constructor move assignment operator) will look like this: if (nullptr != data) delete[] data;

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко You don't need to check if it's a `nullptr`. Just `delete[] data;` In the move assignment, you can simply `std::swap` the pointers of the two containers. No need to `delete[]`.

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко `delete[]` will does nothing on a `nullptr`. You can safely call it on a `nullptr`. @TedLyngmo He/she cannot use `std::swap` neither I guess...

Comment: @simre That's probably true, but figuring out how that works and write a similar function is not too hard.

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко For `clean` if it clears the whole object, you should also reset `cols` and `rows` to 0. Don't leave the object in an invalid state. It can cause headache later pretty easily...

Comment: Your operator= will copy willy-nilly from a n x 2m matrix to a 2n x m matrix.

Comment: @simre: But that was merely an indication of a deeper issue. Why do you believe matrices of different dimensions should not be assignable, if the dimensions are non-const members? OP did not use these semantics.

Comment: @simre Just be aware of that `assert`s are removed in release builds (if `NDEBUG` is defined). If the sizes don't match and the size of the memory you've allocated isn't the same (or perhaps just smaller), you could just `delete[]` the old allocated memory and allocate what's needed to copy the other `Matrix`

Comment: @einpoklum If you move a 2x3 matrix into a 3x2 matrix then what should be the state of the elements not present in the source matrix? What should happen with the elements that have no place in the destination matrix?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: You would change the dimensions, and reallocate if necessary. Which means you could also assign a 10x20 matrix to a 1x1 matrix... of course, it's a matter of what OP was requested to do.

Comment: @einpoklum Changing the dimensions is a possibility too and yes, you would have to reallocate the data then. I understand Matrix to be the mathematical object of a Matrix and then I'm totally fine with the asserts. For a 2-D array with no mathematical sense behind it it could be different.

Comment: "I'm totally fine" - but OP's teachers may not be. So, at the least, your answer must clarify that you an explicit design choice must be made here.

Comment: @simre: Your problem is that you are thinking like a mathematician. This is StackExchange, a _programming_ site, and OP got a _programming_ assignment. By your logic, `std::vector`'s should not be assignable to each other if their sizes are different.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I added an implementation of the move semantics (this is a new world for me). Can you evaluate and say what is wrong and what can be corrected?

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко In the move constructor you don't need `move` since you are dealing with fundamental types and pointers. Also you don't need to allocate memory in the move constructor. You simply "steal it". Copy from the other Matrix, and then you set the other as you did. In the move assign if clean() sets nullptr, and cols, rows=0, then it seems to be fine.   Also you can check `std::exchange`, but it can confuse some people...

Comment: Don't understand why this has -4 votes. It may not be perfect but it does what the OP requested.

Comment: @MartinYork Noone knows. :D Only those who tried to convince me to implement a logical error... :D

Comment: @simre: It does not provide the strong exception guarantee. It does not use the standard copy and swap pattern. It is very inefficient because each element in the array is constructed and then assigned to (bigger deal T is non-trivial). But it works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, if you need common code between methods, the best way is to factor out the common code into (private) helper methods.  For example, you might have a method `alloc_` that has the loop calling `new` and a `free_` that calls `delete`.  Then you could have:

```
Matrix(const Matrix &a) : rows(a.rows), cols(a.cols) {
    alloc_();
    copy_(a);
}
Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &a) {
    free_();
    rows = a.rows;
    cols = a.cols;
    alloc_();
    copy_(a);
}
~Matrix() { free_(); }
```